Can We Automatically change Pipeline variable (ImageVersion) of container app classic Pipeline in AzureDevops and Trigger that pipeline
Can We Automatically change  Pipeline variable (ImageVersion) of container app classic Pipeline in AzureDevops and Trigger that pipeline . I need to Increase Imageversion automatically and run classic pipeline after increasing imageversion.
I tried using some yaml pipeline using API to call variable and increament it then runn pipeline but it is not working . Can u Provide me example how can i increase version and trigger pipeline automatically

Hi @durgaprasadboddu, Welcome to SO. Have you got a chance to check my answer below to use a counter function like $[counter(variables['MinorVersion'], 0)] to define a variable? Hope it may resolve your query in this post. Thx for your time and sharing.

Update
Based on your update, you may define the variable $(ImageVersion) with $[counter(variables['ImageRepository'], 104)], which is automatically incremented with each run of a pipeline against the value of the variable $(ImageRepository)
You haven't shared any details on your current pipeline definition. Here is my sample script for your reference to build docker image and push to my ACR with incremented tag numbers.
az acr login -n $(MyACR)

cd src # Where the Dockerfile locates
docker build -t $(MyACR).azurecr.io/$(ImageRepository):$(ImageVersion) .
docker push $(MyACR).azurecr.io/$(ImageRepository):$(ImageVersion)
echo "ImageVersion - $(ImageVersion)"





You may use the counter function to define a $(PatchVersion) in your classic pipeline like that in the sample below, which is automatically incremented with each run of a pipeline against the value of the variable $(MinorVersion) . The value of $(PatchVersion) in the first run of the pipeline is 0 and in the second run it is 1.  Once the value of the variable $(MinorVersion) is updated to 1, then in the next run of the pipeline, the value of $(PatchVersion) will be reset to 0.


we are using version like v103 v104 etc.. In each trigger when PR raise it need to be automatically increment to next version . If present version is v103 it need to increment to next version v104 and new incremented version is used as tag of the image in container pipeline and pipeline run and image deployed in azure container apps as this veresion. I need to increment this version in pipeline automatically

Can you edit your original post with the updated requirement? Was your pipeline trigged by Build validation? Was it enabled with CI trigger as well, since the version may increase with an individual CI? Please share more details or screenshots in the original post to help understand your current workflow and engage more insights from the community. Don't forget to scrub or remove any sensitive or private information like emails ip token appname, urls etc., as this post is publicly visible.

Hi @durgaprasadboddu, Would you let us know if the updated answer to generate incremental tag numbers can resolve your query in this post? Thx for taking time to share the update.
